# looking for libraries

Tags: jquery, vb.net, razor

I'm beginning in .NET development and don't really know what to use to do some specific actions. I'm also a newbie in AJAX/JavaScript development.

I'm using the mvc3.

I'll have to implement a few things :
-rating systems with 5 stars
-classification of items that are listed inside a table. (e.g. : I want all the people that are older than 20)
-searching inside the whole database (e.g. : I want everything that contains the word "tennis", so, it should give me a table with all the people tha play tennis, than a table with the clubs were people play tennis,...).
-a kind of intellisense (e.g. I add a new person inside the database, and for the field "club", I just want to write the first lettes of the club, and then, I would just have to click on the club to fullfil the field).

I've found plenty of websites that give me a library with some of the things that I need. But, I don't know which one I should choose.

I do need something that is as simple as possible, with examples for razor (I'm using VB.net, but it doesn't matter if it's in c#). If possible, having nothing to install could be great (I know that the Jquery scripts that are installed by default are already great).

sorry if my english is bad, I'm not a english native speaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look into this page there are lots of free libraries :

http://planetofcoders.com/free-net-libraries/

Comment: Thx for the time spent for me. I had already found this list of libraries, as plenty of others. My greatest problem is that I don't know which one I should use. Ain't there any better than others? I don't have time enough to test everything (like everybody I guess), and also have no experience.

Comment: these all have its summary and you can use these libraries according to your requirement.